# Replace unknow string between two strings in bash

Tags: linux, sed

i want to replace a unknown string between two strings.

```
(1(...) 2(...) 3(...))
```

I use:

```
sed -i "s/2(.*)/2(new)/g"
```

but i'm getting. (It take the last ')')

```
(1(hello) 2(new)
```

And i want :

```
(1(...) 2(new) 3(...))
```

Someone can help me please ?

**Edit :**

Thank to the answerers, i have another case:

```
 "data_1": [...], "data_2": [...], "data_3": [...]
```

I want to insert a string between ' "data_2": [ ' and the first occurence of ']' after data_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` uses greedy matching so OP's attempt - `2(.*)` - is going to match the 1st literal `2(` plus the longest string that ends with `)`; consider the following where our match starts with the first `2(` and runs to the last `)`:

```
$ echo '(1(...) 2(...) 3(...) 2(abc) 4(...)) more stuff' | sed 's/2(.*)/2(new)/'
(1(...) 2(new) more stuff
```

To limit the match to the first matching `)` there are a few approaches, one idea is to be explicit about what does and does not match, consider:

```
$ echo '(1(...) 2(...) 3(...) 2(abc) 4(...)) more stuff' | sed 's/2([^)]*)/2(new)/'
(1(...) 2(new) 3(...) 2(abc) 4(...)) more stuff
```

In this the case we use `2([^)]*)` which says to match on `2(` followed by any number of characters that are not a `)` (`[^)]*`) followed by a `)`.

To match on all non-greedy occurrences of `2(...)` (where the `...` means any non-`)` character) we can add the `g`lobal qualifier on the end of the `sed` script, eg:

```
$ echo '(1(...) 2(...) 3(...) 2(abc) 4(...)) more stuff' | sed 's/2([^)]*)/2(new)/g'
(1(...) 2(new) 3(...) 2(new) 4(...)) more stuff
```

Comment: Your answer work very well but i have another case:

"name": [...], "age": [...]

I want to insert string between ' "name": [ ' and the first occurence of ']'

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo '(1(...) 2(...) 3(...))' | sed 's/2\((\.*)\)/2(new)/g'
```

You need to escape the brackets that you are using. to match

Update:  From  Benjamin W's comment

```
echo '(1(...) 2(TIM) 3(...))' | sed -E 's/2\([^)]*\)/2(new)/g'
```

Comment: That assumes literal periods, though. Another way to do non-greedy matching until the next closing parenthesis is `[^)]*`: "match characters other than a closing parenthesis"

Comment: so: echo '(1(...) 2(TIM) 3(...))' | sed -E 's/2\([^)]*\)/2(new)/'

Answer (score 0):

I've tried finding hack solutions for non-greedy pattern matching with `sed`, but have found that `perl` usually seems to get the job done much easier.

Unless you have a specific constraint with using only `sed`, you could:

```
echo "(1(...) 2(...) 3(...))" | perl -pe "s/2(.*?)/2(new)/g"
```

The only difference in the regex is the `?` non-greedy modifier after the `.*`, which matches the first `)`.

The command line options are detailed [here](https://www.perl.com/pub/2004/08/09/commandline.html/). Reference for non-greedy modifier is [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre).